# v-if not execute on reload render

Tags: vuejs3

i've got some trouble with render a list of products.

i've got a v-for loop for product categories and in the same loop im use another v-for that render a products in current category

```
<div class="single-category" v-for="category in products" :key="category.id">
                    <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="product in category.products" :key="product.id">
                            <div class="product-card">
                                <div class="header" style="background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/512x512');"></div>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <h5>{{ product.name }}</h5>
                                    <p v-if="cart.includes(product)">prod in cart</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="footer">
                                    <button @click="productManager(product, 'cart')">➕</button>
                                    <button @click="productManager(product, 'fav')">♥️</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

this is function that receive a cart from local storage

```
checkLocalStorageCart(){
            let localCart = localStorage.getItem('cart')
            if (localCart !== null){
                this.localStorageCart = JSON.parse(localCart)
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('cart',  JSON.stringify([]))
            }
```

products component

```
<products
        :cart="localStorageCart"
        :fav="localStorageFav"
        :products="products"
        @productManager="productManager"
    ></products>
```

and all gonna be ok, but i've got a trouble with v-if directive. when im add to cart or to fav it's ok and i see a (v-if) block but when im reload a page v-if is ignored on render and if cart includes a current product v-if not executes itself

have any ideas about? i try to get around create another component like (product) cause all i need is a view some code block on conditional

im already try to wrote a method that returned a bool on execute and v-if directives

Comment: and another thing about it problem

cart and fav array is available in product v-for loop but maybe this arrays is not defined on render time 

Comment: can we see the example ```cart``` and ```product```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: add more information to post

Comment: When does checkLocalStorageCart() and checkLocalStorageFav() methods execute? is it onBeforeMount() hook? make sure you should call above two before component mounts in render tree.

Comment: thanks for answers but it be my fault.

problem solved by change logic on execute cart and fav from local storage
first im does it with `includes()` methods of array in localStorage and then i noticed on refresh page that if product is already in cart when i call an "productManger()" method it not delete an exist item in localStorage cart but push similar object and after a few call it will remove item from cart

i changed `includes()` method on `findIndex()` and add some changes in logic of receive data from localStorage